# Не изменяется указатель в Delphi

Tags: delphi, pascal, указатели, память, freepascal

```
 ToDel := root^.right;
 ToDel := ToDel^.right;
```

После этих 2 строчек кода root^.right не изменяется.

```
root^.right := root^.right^.right;
```

А после этой изменяется , как сделать что бы в первом случае также изменялось ?

```
    TNode = ^Node;
     Node = record
            key :TKey;
            data :TData;
            left, right,parent:TNode;
         end;
root : TNode;
ToDel: TNode;
```

Comment: что такое `root`, `root^.right` и `root^.right^.right`?

Comment: В Delphi вот эти шапочки: `^` при доступе к указателям, можно не писать: `ToDel := root.right;` И существует соглашение, что при именовании типов используется буква `T`, а указателей `P`. Т.е. у вас должно быть `PNode = ^TNode` и `TNode = record ...`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Все логично. `ToDel := root^.right;` копирует указатель из `right` в `ToDel`. Указатель в `root` и не должен поменяться. Если вам нужно поменять `root`, делайте так:

```
ToDel := root^.right;
root^.right := ToDel^.right;
// здесь нужно освободить память, на которую указывает ToDel, если она вам больше нужна.
```

---

P.S. Типы для структур лучше называть с буквой `T` в начале (от слова *Type*), а типы для указателей называть с буквой `P` в начале (от слова *Pointer*). тогда будет проще и вам и другим разбираться в вашем коде.

```
PNode = ^TNode;
TNode = record
  key: TKey;
  data: TData;
  left: PNode;
  right: PNode;
  parent: PNode;
end;
```

Answer (score 3):

`root^.right` указывает на область памяти, в которой находится структура `Node`. После

```
ToDel := root^.right;
```

`ToDel` тоже указывает на эту же область памяти. В этот момент `root^.right` и `ToDel` - два независимых указателя, которые указывают на одно и то же. От того, что Вы измените `ToDel`, никакой другой указатель не изменится.

*Bonus question:*

После назначения

```
root^.right := root^.right^.right;
```

сохраняется ли где-нибудь старый адрес `root^.right`, и очищается ли память распределенная для этой структуры?